# how to specify default pessimistic_write lock timeout in yaml?

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I want to specify the lock timeout value while acquiring pessimistic write lock for database rows. I found that it can be specified in hibernate or jpa xml property files like this in persistence.xml:

```
<properties>
   <property name="javax.persistence.query.timeout" value="3000"/>
</properties>
```

How can I achieve the same thing for a spring boot's application.yml file?

The following **doesn't** work:

```
spring:
    datasource:
        url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing
        username: test
        password: test123
    jpa:
        show-sql: true
        javax.persistence.lock.timeout: 1000  #DOESN'T WORK
```

Answer (score 0):

Just found out that it works when specified under jpa:hibernate instead of just jpa:

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testing
    username: test
    password: test123
  jpa:
    show-sql: true
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
      javax.persistence.lock.timeout: 2000 #WORKS!
```